# Git cherry-pick a file from a merge commit and retain authorship

Tags: git, github

While I was able to cherry-pick a specific file from a commit, the original commit message could not be maintained after git reset.

```
#cherry-pick a merge commit
git cherry-pick -x -s --edit -m 2 <SHA>

#remove unwanted staged changes
git reset HEAD

#add back the file
git add <file I want to pick on>

#try to continue, but cherry-pick was canceled by reset
#git cherry-pick --continue

#manually add back the commit message and author info
git commit
```

Is there anyway to retain the original message and authorship?

Comment: Start with `git cherry-pick -n`, which doesn't even attempt the commit. This will leave the original's message ready for the later `git commit`. You should not retain the author though, since this construction, of just some files and not others, is your own, and not that author's. It is rather odd to cherry-pick the second parent of a merge in the first place, though, much less to try to get one or just a few files updated that way, so the entire process seems a bit iffy.

Comment: `cherry-pick` always retains the author info and you don't need to do `git commit` after successful pick.

Comment: Don't use `--edit` to retains original message

Comment: @torek for some reason the later git commit is empty after the git reset.

Comment: @torek I'm doing some backporting from a public commit and I need to add some extra info about the commit below the original author's sign-off.

Comment: Don't use a blanket `git reset HEAD` either. Reset only the files that need it, or use `git checkout HEAD -- <paths>` to restore them.